# Spring/Hibernate: New entity-classes in dependend project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an (eclipse-)project which uses spring and hibernate to map some entities:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>Book</value>
            <value>Language</value>
            <value>Person</value>
            <!-- ... -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <!-- ... -->
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now I have an project which depends on this projects and includes the above mentioned bean in its own applicationContext.xml but must add some own entities.

I do not want to add those entity to the bean-definition of the primary project, because they do not belong there.

How can I extend the bean `mySessionFactory` with some new `annotatedClasses` to be used only in the dependend project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using...

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.acme.domain1</value>
        <value>com.acme.domain2</value>
    </list>
<property>
```

This is very like Spring's component-scan feature
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?134056-packagesToScan-in-LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBea-doesn-t-work-if

Comment: Thank you! With `<value>somedomain.**.*</value>` it is also possible to scan sub-packages.